# Find least positive integer $n $ such that $A^n=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find least positive integer $n $ such that $A^n=I$ where $A=$ 
\begin{bmatrix} \sin x && -\sin y\\ \sin y && \sin x\end{bmatrix} where $x=\dfrac{\pi}{18};y=\dfrac{4\pi}{9}$

I tried doing it using multiplication of matrices but that is too cumbersome.

Using $\det A^n=1\implies (\det A)^n=1\implies (\sin^2 x+\sin^2 y )^n=1$ but that too is difficult.

Please give some hints .

Comment: Jordan normal form? You're complexifying? ... Just think of the matrix as representing a linear transformation and think about it geometrically.

Comment: How does geometrical interpretation give you the least positive number $n$?@TedShifrin

Comment: Here's a hint: If multiplication by $A$ rotates the plane angle $\theta$, then multiplication by $A^2$ rotates the plane through what angle?

Comment: It will be $2\theta $@TedShifrin

Comment: So $A^9$ will rotate it by $9\theta $ and hence will be equal to identity ;Right @TedShifrin

Comment: OK, so what angle(s) of rotation give you the identity map? When will multiplication by $A^n$ be the identity?

Comment: Yes, and no smaller power works.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
y=\frac{4\pi}{9} = \frac{\pi}{2} -\frac{\pi}{18} = \frac{\pi}{2} - x
\end{align}
that is
\begin{align}
\sin \frac{4\pi}{9} = \cos\frac{\pi}{18}.
\end{align}
Now, rewrite your matrix using only $x$.

Comment: Don't you really mean using only $y$?